# Let's get critical: Dec 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Ebooks Stack Exchange](http://ebooks.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 7 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: So this time not enough posts to get 10 questions for review :-/

Comment: Our visits per day are increasing, but our question rate is declining. Actually I just checked the analytics and our question rate steadily declined from Jan/14 to Jul/14 and then has been consistent for the remainder of the year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How to remove an article from kindle and Amazon cloud permanently](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/2538/how-to-remove-an-article-from-kindle-and-amazon-cloud-permanently)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Tracking time spent reading on a kindle?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/2536/tracking-time-spent-reading-on-a-kindle)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [I only see the download links for DRMed ebooks on my Kobo Library](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/2565/i-only-see-the-download-links-for-drmed-ebooks-on-my-kobo-library)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Is there a way to sync reading progress across multiple devices and platforms?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/2554/is-there-a-way-to-sync-reading-progress-across-multiple-devices-and-platforms)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [What CSS can I use to change the background color of an epub on a Nook HD?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/2530/what-css-can-i-use-to-change-the-background-color-of-an-epub-on-a-nook-hd)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Can I share premium ebooks online for free?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/2557/can-i-share-premium-ebooks-online-for-free)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Amazon eBook Self-Publishing vs Major Publishing Houses](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/2555/amazon-ebook-self-publishing-vs-major-publishing-houses)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---